# SqlCommand ExecuteReader as HttpWebRequest

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, ado.net, network-programming, httpwebrequest

I have multiple clients. Each client has a local Sql Server and multiple WinForms apps that access the local db via ADO.NET (in a Data Access Layer). I want to centralize the db's at one facility.

A VPN is not an option.

The problem then arises: how does one implement this quickly without converting all the WinForms Apps to Web Apps (or other deep refactoring)?

All considerations of performance aside... I know you can transmit [DataSets over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561203/can-i-serialize-a-data-table-or-data-set-to-transfer-over-a-web-service-in-c), but how would you go about sending SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(), etc. requests via HTTP?

Essentially I'm looking to make the transition as transparent to the existing apps as possible.

Perhaps extending SqlCommand and override related methods? Some kind of Sql Server [Proxy](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternProxy.aspx)?

Comment: Wasn't the purpose of writing a "Data Access Layer" in the first place to enable you to do just this? You yank out one DAL, and drop in another instead.

Comment: The DAL is quite large and involved. And there is also the issue of a receiving end. Not options desired... But if you see that is the only way to go, perhaps you could provide some code examples? It's a C# project.